# FQL 'Try this Query' links are broken?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Been spending some time trying to get a solution in place that will determine if a user logged into our application via facebook PHP SDK. Due to a number of redirects and session clears, I am looking into using FQL, but when when reading the docs I noticed the 'Try this query' links appear to be broken.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/cookies/

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Lol, forgot to replace <uid> with a number, but the &access_token = seems to be breaking it. I changed the query around a bit and put access_token first and got what appears to be a positive response: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=123|123&query=select%20uid,%20name,%20value,%20expires,%20path%20from%20cookies%20where%20uid%20%3D%201274471514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Facebook changed the contents of the link from the OP, but when it was valid the links weren't working as expected so I had to manipulate the test queries a bit to get them to work. As mentioned in my comment the following worked:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=123|123&query=select%20uid,%20name,%20value,%20expires,%20path%20from%20cookies%20where%20uid%20%3D%201274471514